# Measure CPU load average on Linux (excluding disk load)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, load

The load average on Linux (`/proc/loadavg`, also reported by `uptime` and `top`, etc) is a measure of both CPU and disk load:

From [`man 5 proc`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc):

> ```
>    /proc/loadavg
>           The first three fields in this file  are  load  average  figures
>           giving  the number of jobs in the run queue (state R) or waiting
>           for disk I/O (state D) averaged over 1, 5, and 15 minutes.  They
>           are  the same as the load average numbers given by uptime(1) and
>           other programs.  The fourth field consists of two numbers  sepa-
>           rated  by a slash (/).  The first of these is the number of cur-
>           rently  executing   kernel   scheduling   entities   (processes,
>           threads); this will be less than or equal to the number of CPUs.
>           The value after the slash is the  number  of  kernel  scheduling
>           entities that currently exist on the system.  The fifth field is
>           the PID of the process that was most  recently  created  on  the
>           system.
> ```

I'd really like to find a load average metric for **just the CPU load** (the number of jobs in the run queue (state R), **excluding** jobs waiting for disk I/O (state D).  Does anyone know if I can get this?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is "No, you can't."

The following specifics refer to kernel version 3.8. Locations of some variable and function definitions have changed over time, so this does not apply to latest kernel nor the kernels older than 3.4.

Calculated load averages are stored in a three slot array of `struct taskinfo` ([source](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/sysinfo.h?v=3.8#L7)). Load averages are also tossed around in another three slot array, `avenrun[3]`, defined in `kernel/sched/core.c` (see [this](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/core.c?v=3.8#L2089)). The load average values excluding threads waiting for I/O simply aren't calculated, so you'd have to fiddle with how things are calculated in `kernel/sched/core.c` (see, for example functions `calc_load_n()` and `calc_global_nohz` [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/core.c?v=3.8#L2313)).

Answer (score 3):

/proc/loadavg is calculated by keeping track of {number of running tasks + number io waiting tasks}, sampling rate is 5 seconds.

so, I thinks this make it possible:

if you want to keep track of only the numbers of running tasks, you could make a simple application that reads /proc/stat periodically and prints out exponential moving average on procs_running.